# wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick

I want to upload photos to my website. After i selected the photos and click on "Add Photos" this error comes up. Any ideas how i can solve this?[image]

photos_controller.rb

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController

def create
@wall = Wall.find(params[:wall_id])

if params [:images]
  params[:images].each do |img|
    @wall.photos.create(image: img)
  end

  @photos = @wall.photos
  redirect_back(fallback_location: request.referer, notice: "Saved...")

 end

end
end
```

walls.controller.rb

```
class WallsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_wall, except: [:index, :new, :create]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]
  before_action :is_authorised, only: [:listing, :pricing, :description, :photo_upload, :location, :update]

  def index
    @walls = current_user.walls
  end

  def new
    @wall = current_user.walls.build
  end

  def create
    @wall = current_user.walls.build(wall_params)
    if @wall.save
      redirect_to listing_wall_path(@wall), notice: "Saved..."
    else
      fash[:alert] = "Something went wrong..."
      render :new
    end
  end


  def photo_upload
    @photos = @wall.photos
  end

  def location
  end

  def update
    if @wall.update(wall_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Saved..."
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Something went wrong..."
    end
    redirect_back(fallback_location: request.referer)
  end

  private

    def set_wall
      @wall = Wall.find(params[:id])
    end

    def is_authorised
      redirect_to root_path, alert: "You don't have permission" unless current_user.id == @wall.user_id
    end

    def wall_params
      params.require(:wall).permit(:size_sqm, :visibility, :traffic, :wall_name, :summary, :address, :price)
    end

end
```

Comment: You appear to have a space between `params` and `[:images]`, here: `if params [:images]`.

Comment: And in Ruby, that means you're calling `params` with one argument, the one-element array `[:images]`.

Answer (score 1):

In a Rails controller action, `params` is a Hash value and a Hash value is fetched like below:

```
params[:name]
```

In your code you're having an unwanted space between `params` and `[:images]` which means translates to calling a method by name `params`