# Proper forming of API requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following command in the console:

```
curl 'https://3b803ce956aa.ngrok.io/api/v1/send' -i --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Content-Type: application/json"  -H 'Accept-Charset: utf-8' -H 'Authorization: Token token="GeUPm5xoxQFXR0ijJOZ6W6xr2ME1wZUWiaB3PLg9uZ8uGhFFDE7YnqCjFQwcCs0zgbtHjIiuc2jxo4I5"' -d '{"server_id":1,"building_id":1}'
```

but also with a version

```
--data '{"server_id":1,"building_id":1}'
```

is being received by the API controller.   The routes are defined as:

```
namespace  :api  do
  namespace  :v1 do
    post 'send', to: 'messages#send', defaults: { format: :json }
```

However, the handling of the requests is failing, in both cases, as it receives and returns:

```
Processing by Api::V1::MessagesController#send as JSON
  Parameters: {"server_id"=>1, "building_id"=>1, "message"=>{"server_id"=>1, "building_id"=>1}}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)):
```

where the controller action

```
def send
  @request = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
  @messagelog = Messagelog.create(server_id: params[:server_id], building_id: params[:building_id]
  [...]
```

Two oddities appear:

1. the fact that the parameters are repeated with the contents of the parameters as part of the message
2. the action expects 0 arguments
   I do not understand why the parameters get interpreted twice (this is a sub-question..).  How can the API controller action be construed to accept the parameters?

Comment: Have you defined strong params in that controller? Also, can you post the whole stacktrace of the request when you make the CURL request, don't omit.

Comment: No I had not.  I since have, but am still receiving the identical argument error.  Attempting: `def send(*)` does process the action, but multiplied by the number of params which is naturally not desired.  The above posted is the complete trace save the indication of the line of the error, which matches the `def send` statement

Comment: Show your `rails routes` please

Comment: Controller action definitely have no parameters, so please check your code for syntax errors like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50843008/wrong-number-of-arguments-given-1-expected-0)

Comment: I have updated the question to reflect the routes. Note that with controller action as def send a mismatch in arguments arises. I have managed to process the action with a dummy placeholder def send(server=9)

Answer (score 0):

By default Rails wraps JSON request parameters into a hash guessing its name from controller class. You can read details [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html).

So if you don't need this "guessed" hash in your `params` just remove `:json` from `:format` array in `config\initializers\wrap_parameters.rb`. Or you can use fine-grained control at the controller level as described above.